# Elastic search wildcard words within a keyword

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, lucene

We have a similar mapping to this one:

```
PUT my_index
{
    "mappings": {
        "_doc": {
            "properties": {
                "tags": {
                    "type":  "keyword"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And documents like this...
1)TERM1-TERM2-TERM4-TERM3 
2)TERM1-TERM2-TERM5-TERM3

Using an expression like this

```
GET /my_index/_doc/_search
{
    "query": {
        "regexp": {
            "tag": "TERM1.*TERM3" 
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to match with the documents since I am matching the whole keyword with the regex.
But the matching that I really need is something like TERM2-*-TERM3, where * matches only with a WORD, and not with many words. Is it possible to achieve what I like?
Another expression that I would like to write is TERM1-*-*-TERM3
Matching both documents too.

Thanks

Comment: Try `TERM1-(.*[^A-Za-z0-9_])?TERM2([^A-Za-z0-9_].*)?-TERM3`. The second one should be `TERM1-[^-]*-[^-]*-TERM3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match a document starting with `TERM1` and ending with `TERM3` having as whole word `WORD` anywhere in between, you may use

```
TERM1-(.*[^A-Za-z0-9_])?WORD([^A-Za-z0-9_].*)?-TERM3
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vE1cH0/1).

**Details**

- `TERM1-` - `TERM1-` at the start of the string
- `(.*[^A-Za-z0-9_])?`- an optional sequence of any 0+ chars other than newline as many as possible and then any non-word char
- `WORD` - a literal `WORD`
- `([^A-Za-z0-9_].*)?` - an optional sequence of any non-word char and then any 0+ chars other than newline as many as possible
- `-TERM3` - `-TERM3` at the end of the string.

To solve the second issue, you may just use negated bracket expressions:

```
TERM1-[^-]*-[^-]*-TERM3
```

where `[^-]*` matches any 0+ chars other than `-`. See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vE1cH0/2/).

NOTE: in the demos, I am using `^` and `$` to make the patterns match the whole lines (with `m` modifier). Do not use them in ES as matching is anchored at string boundaries implicitly.

Comment: Thanks for replying, (.*[^A-Za-z0-9_])? consumes more than a word, I need something like TERM1-\*-TERM4, where '\*' is only a word.

Comment: @MarcosMussio Then just use `TERM1-WORD-TERM3`, what is the problem? Please provide a real life scenario otherwise.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, TERM1-[^-]*-[^-]*-TERM3 is all what I needed. :)